# Is it OK to run perfmon on production servers? And why?

Tags: sql-server, performance, performance-tuning, perfmon

Or should perfmon be limited to a Dev/QA server with load tests that simulate production activity?

I'd like to run perfmon for two days ([like Sql Server master Brent Ozar suggests](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2006/12/dba-101-using-perfmon-for-sql-performance-tuning/)) to get an overall feel of my web app's database performance.

Comment: Some people have suggested using a SQL Trace - be cautious with SQL trace and never trace all activity on a prod server.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

SQL Server, and most other products, generate the counters all the time, no matter if there are listeners or not (ignoring the -x startup option). Counter tracing is completely transparent on the application being monitored. There is a shared memory region on which the monitored application writes and from which monitoring sessions read the raw values at the specified interval. So the only cost associated with monitoring is the cost of the monitoring process and the cost to write of the sampled values to disk. Choosing a decent collection interval (I usually choose 15 sec) and a moderate number of counters (50-100), and writing into a binary file format usually leaves no impact on the monitored system.

But I'd recommend against using Perfmon (as in perfmon.exe). Instead get yourself familiar with with logman.exe, see [Description of Logman.exe, Relog.exe, and Typeperf.exe Tools](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303133). This way you don't tie the collection session to your session. Logman, being a command line tool, can be used in scripts and scheduled jobs to start and stop collection sessions.

Comment: I am using TypePerf.exe with DSN to insert data directly into tables. There is a separate db for them. Will it in any way affect?

Answer (score 15):

There's nothing wrong with running perfmon on production boxes.  It's relatively low key, and can gather a lot of good info for you.  And how would you accurately simulate production loads if you didn't run some analysis on the production server?  From Brent Ozar in your own link:

> Let Perfmon run for a day or two to
>   gather a good baseline of the server’s
>   activity. It’s not that invasive on
>   the SQL Server being monitored, and
>   the in-depth results will pay off. The
>   more data we have, the better job we
>   can do on analyzing the Perfmon
>   results.

I've run perfmon on a number of production Exchange boxes with no adverse effects.

Comment: Agreed - there's no overhead from running Perfmon.  Another answer suggested running Profiler instead of Perfmon, but there is a very real overhead to running Profiler.  I've seen Profiler traces take down production servers when the tracing box couldn't keep up with the load, or when the added load pushed the production server over the edge.

Comment: Thanks for chiming in @Brent.  By the way, I bought your [2008 internals book](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0470484284/) yesterday.

Comment: Ah, cool!  Let me know what you think of it.

Answer (score 8):

Ever since I listened to [Clint Huffman](http://blogs.technet.com/clinth/), who wrote [PAL](http://pal.codeplex.com/) a utility for analyzing Perfmon Logs, on a podcast once. I have setup what I call the Flight Recorder on all of our production application servers. This practice has come in very handy for diagnosing problems and monitoring trends.

Below is the script I use to setup an auto-starting Perfmon Collector, with log purging. If desired, it can be fed a file listing performance counters to collect (one per line) or a PAL Threshold XML file. I like to use the PAL Threshold files.

```
<#
Install-FlightRecorder.ps1
.SYNOPSIS
Installs or sets up the pieces necessary to create PerfMon Collector 
snapshots, one a minute, to a file located in C:\FlightRecorder.

.DESCRIPTION
Installs or sets up the pieces necessary to create PerfMon Collector 
snapshots, one a minute, to a file located in C:\FlightRecorder.

.PARAMETER Path
File listing performance counters to collect, one per line. 
Or a PAL Threshold XML file.

#>
[CmdletBinding()]
param (
    [string]$Path
)

#Requires -RunAsAdministrator
$ScriptDir = { Split-Path $MyInvocation.ScriptName –Parent }
$DeleteTempFile = $False

function Main {
    if (-not $Path) { $Path = DefaultFile $Path }
    if (-not (Test-Path $Path)) {
        Write-Warning "Path does not exist or is inaccessable: $Path"
        Exit 1
    }
    if ($Path -like '*.xml') { $Path = PALFile $Path }

    Install-FlightRecorder
    if ($Path.startswith($env:TEMP)) {Remove-Item $Path}
    Write-Verbose 'Installation Successful.'
}

function Install-FlightRecorder {
    Write-Verbose 'Setting up the Flight Recorder.'
    if (-not (Test-Path c:\FlightRecorder\)) {
        mkdir c:\FlightRecorder | out-null 
    }
    if ((LOGMAN query) -match 'FlightRecorder') {
        Write-Verbose 'Removing former FlightRecorder PerfMon Collector.'
        LOGMAN stop FlightRecorder | out-null
        LOGMAN delete FlightRecorder | Write-Verbose
    }
    Write-Verbose 'Creating FlightRecorder PerfMon Collector.'
    LOGMAN create counter FlightRecorder -o "C:\FlightRecorder\FlightRecorder_$env:computername" -cf $Path -v mmddhhmm -si 00:01:00 -f bin | Write-Verbose
    SCHTASKS /Create /TN FlightRecorder-Nightly /F /SC DAILY /ST 00:00 /RU SYSTEM /TR 'powershell.exe -command LOGMAN stop FlightRecorder; LOGMAN start FlightRecorder; dir c:\FlightRecorder\*.blg |?{ $_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-3)} | del' | Write-Verbose
    SCHTASKS /Create /TN FlightRecorder-Startup /F /SC ONSTART /RU SYSTEM /TR "LOGMAN start FlightRecorder" | Write-Verbose
    SCHTASKS /Run /TN FlightRecorder-Startup | Write-Verbose
}

function DefaultFile {
    Write-Warning 'Counter or PAL file not specified, using default configuration.'
    $DeleteTempFile = $True
    $Path = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempFileName()
    Set-Content -Encoding ASCII $Path @'
\LogicalDisk(*)\Avg. Disk sec/Read
\LogicalDisk(*)\Avg. Disk sec/Write
\LogicalDisk(*)\Disk Transfers/sec
\LogicalDisk(C:)\Free Megabytes
\Memory\% Committed Bytes In Use
\Memory\Available MBytes
\Memory\Committed Bytes
\Memory\Free System Page Table Entries
\Memory\Pages Input/sec
\Memory\Pages/sec
\Memory\Pool Nonpaged Bytes
\Memory\Pool Paged Bytes
\Memory\System Cache Resident Bytes
\Network Interface(*)\Bytes Total/sec
\Network Interface(*)\Output Queue Length
\Paging File(*)\% Usage
\Paging File(*)\% Usage Peak
\PhysicalDisk(*)\Avg. Disk sec/Read
\PhysicalDisk(*)\Avg. Disk sec/Write
\Process(_Total)\Handle Count
\Process(_Total)\Private Bytes
\Process(_Total)\Thread Count
\Process(_Total)\Working Set
\Processor(*)\% Interrupt Time
\Processor(*)\% Privileged Time
\Processor(*)\% Processor Time
\System\Context Switches/sec
\System\Processor Queue Length
'@
    $Path
}

function PalFile {
    $DeleteTempFile = $True
    $InputPath = $Path
    $Path = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempFileName()
    $filesRead = @()
    Read-PalFile $InputPath | Select -Unique | sort | Set-Content -Encoding ASCII $Path
    $Path
}

$script:filesRead =@()
function Read-PalFile ([string]$path) {
    if (-not (Test-Path $path)) {
        Write-Warning "PAL Threshold file not found: $path"
        return
    }
    if ($script:filesRead -contains $path) {return}
    $script:filesRead += @($path)
    Write-Verbose "Reading PAL Threshold file: $path"
    $xml = [XML](Get-Content $path)
    $xml.SelectNodes('//DATASOURCE[@TYPE="CounterLog"]') | select -expand EXPRESSIONPATH
    $xml.SelectNodes('//INHERITANCE/@FILEPATH') | select -expand '#text' | where {$_ } | ForEach {
        $newpath = Join-Path (Split-Path -parent $path) $_
        Write-Debug "Inheritance file: $newpath"
        Read-PalFile $newpath
    }
}

. Main
```

Comment: Does this script need anything to be installed (PAL or anything else)? Can you please provide a sample of the output file it generates if possible? Sorry I do not know PowerShell.

Comment: There is nothing to install. This script configures native Windows features. It creates a PerMon collector, plus two scheduled tasks. One task, starts the PerfMon collector after a reboot. The other task, cleans up old log files. If you would like to analyze your PerfMon files with PAL, I would recommend PAL be setup and ran on a non-production server. For easy setup, this will read a PAL configuration file.

Answer (score 3):

We do it quite frequently.  It is also essential for establishing a baseline in the real environment, so you can compare later if there are issues or you need to perform a capacity study.

I recommend not going below a 10-second interval though.  If you are collecting many objects/counters and the interval is too frequent, it may impact operations.

Microsoft has a PerfMon Wizard that will setup the task for you.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=31FCCD98-C3A1-4644-9622-FAA046D69214&displaylang=en

Comment: I see that the PerfMon Wizard was released in 2004. I wonder if it comes standard with SQL Server 2005.

Comment: I think that version is still current.

Answer (score 2):

In an ideal world where a production server exactly mirrors what a dev server, does and is also an exact duplicate of the dev server, perfmon should never be required on the production server because the results would be the same as those on the dev server. Of course that mythical situation never happens, so we do need to run perfmon on production servers and there is absolutely nothing wrong with that. Amongst other things, we may need to use perfmon and other tools to learn why the production server isn't behaving the same as the dev server.

Answer (score 2):

Why perfmon? I mean, recent versions of SQL server have their own method of doing that including building a (central) data warehouse of performance counters that can then be queried and reported against. There is zero sense in running perfmon there.

I am, like always, astonished by all the posts here of people who obviously never read the documentation ;)

http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-server-2008-performance-data-collector/ is a good start. IMHO that should work on almost every sql server that is used for production purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with running Perfmon as many have suggested, but I would run Profiler instead or in addition, with the same caveats, don't capture too much too often, just capture long running queries, i.e. duration > x seconds, or cpu > xx, or reads > xxxx; very little impact, and you'll quickly see the queries that would benefit most from tuning.

Comment: what do you use as base thresholds of duration, cpu, and reads?

Comment: It depends on the app, but I would start with duration > (max time I would want any user to wait for anything); start too high, 10 seconds or more, if you get nothing, great, back it down a bit. Guaranteed you'll have some surprises "float" to the top.

Comment: ..and I would start with duration, only use CPU if you think you are CPU-bound, read or write counters if you are I/O-bound, but use duration if you're not sure where the bottlenecks lie, or just, like you said, trying to get a feel for what's going on.